# Is there a simple thing I can do to stop websites from blocking scrolling?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, scrolling

Some websites, especially news websites, stop you from scrolling through a page in order to force you to sign up, pay money, click a popup etc. It's easy to get rid of popups with an element blocker, but is there a way to turn scrolling back on?

The content is still there and can be seen with a "reader mode" extension, but that often mangles the page enough to be really annoying, gets rid of images etc. The content is even there if you zoom out enough!

EDIT: This stackoverflow question has some technical workarounds that involve messing with the code, but I'm looking for something much more convenient that doesn't involve interacting with the code for the website.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360138/how-to-enable-scrolling-on-website-that-disabled-scrolling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply download Custom JavaScript for Websites 2.

[Link To Download Custom JavaScript for Websites 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk)

Then, click on CJS Extension. You have to find `New RegExp` and enter `.*`

Finally, type the following javascript -

`document.body.style.overflow = "visible";`

Click on save. This will inject all that code automatically to all websites.

EDIT : A Simpler way to do this -
1. Open any web page and select bookmark this page.
2. Type any preferred name. For e.g. - Scroll.
3. Click on More Option.
4. Replace the URL with the following command - 
`javascript:void(document.body.style.overflow = "visible");`
5. Save the bookmark.
Now when your scrollbar is blocked, simply click on this bookmark. Instead of opening the url, it will execute the the javascript. :)

Comment: Maybe !important would help?

Comment: I just got a much better answer. If you need it, I can edit my answer. It uses bookmarklet.

Comment: sure, feel free to edit or add another answer.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta others are also interested in the answer to this, so please post your updated answer!

Comment: @ETL I have updated my answer. It would be nice if you tell which of the 2 was more convenient.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta thanks, the bookmarklet is super simple! As an alternative third option, could this be executed with a custom userscript (e.g. in Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey/etc)? And if I did option 1 to inject it on all sites, is there any risk that it would break some websites?

Comment: Or, instead of tinkering with Bookmarks, this is what I did in  Google Chrome: press F12 to pull up the browser's internal "Developer Tools" area, go to Console tab, click/make-sure I can type a command in the console okay, paste in **document.body.style.overflow = "visible";** (all on one line of text) and then press Enter, test/verify/enjoy results, press F12 to make the browser's internal "Developer Tools" stop taking up space on the screen, and then continue enjoying result.  Thanks, Bhavya Gupta, for the working JS code.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems since you asked for a easy way to do it, I hope this will help others.

Step 1:
[Ublock Origin extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm)

Step 2:
[Logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42KWe.png)
Use Logger and refresh page

Step 3:
Find an event like this
[p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8oL7.png)
[p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwZPo.png)

Step 4:
Create Rule, preferable removing the tail of url
[p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0SkK.png)
[p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWxFf.png)

Step 5:
Refresh and enjoy scrolling for an unlimited time

tags (stop websites scroll blocking)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).